# How to add bindings in devops pipeline with Yaml

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

How I can add Bindings in a "IIS web app manage" task using yaml?
I tried putting the bindings like classic pipeline and doesnt work

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a JSon with all information like this:

```
                                {
                                        "bindings":[{
                                            "protocol":"http",
                                            "ipAddress":"*",
                                            "port":"xxxxx",
                                            "sslThumbprint":"",
                                            "sniFlag":false
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "protocol":"http",
                                            "ipAddress":"*",
                                            "hostname":"yyyyyy.com",
                                            "port":"80",
                                            "sslThumbprint":"",
                                            "sniFlag":false
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "protocol":"http",
                                            "ipAddress":"*",
                                            "hostname":"xxxxxxxx.com",
                                            "port":"80",
                                            "sslThumbprint":"",
                                            "sniFlag":false
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-management-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet or https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroupV0/README.md mentioned the format expected!?

Comment: can someone please point out where you put the above JSON ??

Comment: @JohnJoseph I've added an answer with an example

Comment: any idea how would you make the port a variable ?

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer doesn't give a great example on usage. The `Bindings` input accepts a multiline string formatted as a particular JSON object. Also be sure to set `AddBinding: true` as it appears it will ignore the `Bindings` input without it.

On a related note, if you are storing your certificates in WebHosting (as opposed to MY), the deployment will fail as the task won't be able to find your certificate. [Here's the relevant github enhancement to fix this](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-extensions/issues/817)

```
task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
displayName: 'IIS Web App Manage'
inputs:
    IISDeploymentType: 'IISWebsite'
    ActionIISWebsite: 'CreateOrUpdateWebsite'
    ...
    AddBinding: true
    Bindings: |
        {
            bindings:[
                {
                    "protocol":"http",
                    "ipAddress":"*",
                    "hostname":"mywebsite.com",
                    "port":"80",
                    "sslThumbprint":"",
                    "sniFlag":false
                },
                {
                    "protocol":"https",
                    "ipAddress":"*",
                    "hostname":"mywebsite.com",
                    "port":"443",
                    "sslThumbprint":"...",
                    "sniFlag":true
                 }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: any idea how would you make the port a variable ?

Comment: Use Azure Pipelines variables or template parameters.

Comment: For those wondering what the format of the "bindings" option should be (I couldn't find any documentation for it), I think I've found it in the source code: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroupV0/Utility.ps1#L49